# JQuery UI dialog shows without any styles applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used the example from here http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated to create a dialog box. The problem is that it is transparent, without any styles. Also when I click on the button again it never shows. What's wrong?

I use JQuery by using this code -

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the relevant themes are loading correctly?

Comment: I have no idea, I used google link to Jquery and UI.

Comment: shouldnt the theme load automatically?

Comment: That will just provide the markup by default. Try here http://jqueryui.com/ and use Build Custom Download.

Answer (score 6):

You need to also include the jQuery UI stylesheet. the default one can be found here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

There are a selection of themes available, you can either use one of the predefined or make your own using the clever [jQuerryUI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Answer (score 0):

As above in the comments:

If you'd rather not use the Google CDN for whatever reason (offline development, whatever) then [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/) will allow you to roll your own version of the UI code with only the necessary bits (with dependancy checking) and your choice of themes.